# Package xr prints ref number then label

Tags: cross-referencing, labels, xr

Here's my MWE.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[margin=2.4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{%
    amsmath,
    amsfonts,
    amsthm,
    mathpazo,
    tgbonum,
    xr,
    graphicx,
    enumitem,
    ccicons
}

\externaldocument{../../notas/algsup}

\begin{document}
    
We have the result proved elsewhere:

\newtheorem*{propext}{Proposition \ref{prop:triang}}

\begin{propext}
Humpty is unbreakable.
\end{propext}

\end{document}
```

When I compile I get the text Proposition 2.9prop2.9, as shown in the attachment. I tried removing the colon from the name of the label in the original file (and obviously in the one I'm trying to compile) but I still get the "prop" part.

I made a test with a file in the same directory and it compiled without the label name before the colon. I made hard links to both the .TEX and .AUX files I'm importing, but I got the same result.

I included my whole preamble in case there's an incompatibility with a package I am using.

How can I fix this? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: this document doesn't use hyperref, but probably the one you are referencing does? hyperref changes the internal format simplest if both do (then use xr-hyper package) or both do not

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Thou art a Gentleman and a Scholar! Indeed, adding hyperref to the target solved the issue. Could you please make your comment an answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This document doesn't use `hyperref`, but probably the one you are referencing does? `hyperref` changes the internal format. It is simplest if both do (then use `xr-hyper` package) or both do not.

In an ideal world you would not need two packages and `xr` would be able to gracefully handle mixtures of documents using or not using `hyperref` but unfortunately that's harder than it ought to be to do in a compatible way.